# Detect errors and build report in case of failure in shake build

Tags: shake-build-system

I'm using shake for a test suite. I have multiples independent tests represented as a set of `Rule`. If any of theses rules fails, the test fails. Finally, I produce a report containing all the tests status.

My issues are :

a) I need to detect which test runs or fails. Actually I'm cheating using `actionOnException`, but that's lot of boilerplate in each command in each rules and that's complicated (I must write status file or play with `IORef` to store the failing status).

b) I want to write the Shake report as part of my final report, however `shakeReport` does not write the file in case of error, my only solution is to run again the build using `--no-build --report out.html` which is not convenient.

Edit: Actually the tests are in action and build their dependencies. The build roughly looks like :

```hs
main = do
  -- when this fails, `dumpTests` is called,
  -- but the shake report is not written
  _ <- (try shakeMain) :: IO (Either SomeException ())

  -- This write my test report from the success informations it can gather
  -- in the directory hierarchy
  dumpTests

smakeMain = shakeArgs {shakeStaunch=True, shakeReport=["report.html"]} $ do

   "tests" ~> need ["test1/done", "test2/done", ...]

   -- this rules completly runs a test
   "*/done" %> \done -> do
       let test = takeDirectory done
       -- clear all the leftover to be sure that there is nothing useless left. This is important because I use theses outputs to know which command succeeds or fails.
       liftIO $ removeFiles test ["stdout.log", "*/image/*.exr", "*/image/*.png", "done"]

       need [test </> "stdout.log"]

       results <- getDirectoryFiles (test </> "image") ["*.exr"]

       need (map (-<.> "png") results)

       writeFile' done "done"

   "*/stdout.log" %> \log -> do
        let path = takeDirectory log </> "test"
        need [path]

        aCmd path -- this builds stdout.log and all exrs

   "*/image/*.png" %> \png -> do
         need [(png -<.> "exr")]
         toExr png
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are the tests in `Action` or `IO`? Do they "build" their dependencies first?

Comment: Example added, everything is in `Action`/`Rule` except the final report creation. Actually I'll be happy to have the final report creation in a `Rule`, but I need a way of creating it even if its dependencies fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question b is simplest to answer. If the build raises an error it won't write out a report - it's reasonable that could be changed (I can see arguments both ways). However, you can automate the `--no-build` piece by having `main` call `shake` twice - first as you do now, and second with `withArgs` or using `shake shakeOptions{shakeReport=...} mempty`. Essentially you do exactly what you are doing now "by hand", but put it into the `main` function so it's automatic.

For the main question, I suspect the answer is you should be marking fails not with exceptions, but with a result value. For example, `test1/done` could record a TRUE/FALSE saying whether the test worked or not. Then you can have `alldone` which depends on all the `*/done` values and writes a single report. That way your build would always pass (unless you got something fundamentally wrong), but the result on passing would be either "TESTS PASS" or "TESTS FAIL".

Comment: For the main question, your solution works, however it forces me to think about cleaning the test1/done before attempting the command, because if the command fails for any reason, the test1/done will keep the results of the previous attempt, which may be misleading. However you confirmed that there is no easy "out of the box" solution, which is a satisfying answer for me. Thank you.

Comment: If the test1/done rule always succeeds (as far as Shake is concerned), but success/failure of the test is written down to a file, then everything will always be updated properly.

Comment: PS. If you want to discuss more thoroughly the mailing list or github tracker might be a better venue, and we can update SO with the answer afterwards (both linked from the bottom of http://shakebuild.com/)